# Inverse Laplace Transform of Polynomial

Tags: integral-transforms, inverse-laplace

I'm trying to find the inverse laplace transform of the following function:

> [image]

The resulting inverse laplace is in the form:

> [image]

Not sure where the derivatives came from, or what the inverse laplace of a polynomial is, as I couldn't find it on LT table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplication by $s$ in the Laplace domain corresponds to differentiation in time. Thus, $f^{(n)}(t) \iff s^n F(s)$.

Similarly, division by $s$ in the Laplace domain corresponds to integration in time.